# FLutter web does not select the environment that I indicate

Tags: flutter, build, environment-variables

I recently had to work with environments in flutter and define the environment my project goes to at project build time, so I created my 2 development environments .env.stg and .env.prod. Everything works fine when trying to run the project with the command **flutter run -d chrome --dart-define=ENVIRONMENT= .env.stg**, as when viewing the content of my index.html it changes as it should according to the environment that tells you.
The problem is when I build the project, for some reason, no matter how much I define the environment, it doesn't change to the one I indicate, I know because the validations I have are not given in my index and a different content. is displayed than it should depending on the environment
**flutter build web --dart-define=ENVIRONMENT=.env.stg**
await dotenv.load(fileName: const String.fromEnvironment("ENVIRONMENT"));
That way I access my defined variable
Do you have any idea what could be the problem?

I have tried with the dart:io library to access the environment variable but it returns that it is not supported, I currently have version 3.7.10 of flutter

It is supposed that with the define it should work as it happens when I run the project